# What is causing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token finally" in angular on android browser?

Tags: android, angularjs

I have a hard time debuging this error. It is angularjs 1.3.10. It seems like android browser finds an error in angular's code which is quite wired.

EDIT:
Android browser javascript console says: ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.js:16035 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token finally

It is android 2.3.3

Comment: You need to provide the code where the error is occurring.. Check your JS Console for clues.

Comment: Android browser javascript console says: ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.js:16035 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token finally

Comment: Guys I am getting downvoted but I have spent a lot of time googling this issue and nothing comes up. It is my first angularjs application and I dont have the skill to debug angularjs yet. I have no 'finally' tokens in my codebase

Comment: You are being downvoted because you need yo provide the codr where your error is occuring. Juet telling us you havd an error doesnt help....

Comment: It clearly findes an error in angular.js file. If 16035 means the character no the file then there is this snippet:                                                          `
/**
 * Determines if a value is a regular expression object.
 *
 * @private
 * @param {*} value Reference to check.
 * @returns {boolean} True if `value` is a `RegExp`.
 */`   it doesnt seem relevant at all

Comment: Dayen thank you for your help I am a novice Stackoverflow poster. Well android javascript console doesnt give me much else to share just this error in angularjs file. It is exacly as written in second comment

Comment: Put this information in your question.

Comment: [Which version](http://www.whatsmyua.com/) of browser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are running angular (1.3.10) on Android Browser 2.x.

`finally` is a reserved Ecmascript 3 keyword and the following syntax is not allowed in ES3 :

```
return $http.get(tpl, httpOptions)
  .finally(function() {
  ^^^^^^^^
  // This is the line 16035 of unminified angular 1.3.10
    handleRequestFn.totalPendingRequests--;
  })
```

In ES3, it has to be written with the bracket notation :

```
return $http.get(tpl, httpOptions)
  ['finally'](function() {
    handleRequestFn.totalPendingRequests--;
  })
```

Same goes for other reserved keywords as `catch`.

**EDIT**: Here is the [related issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11153)

There is a comment about the issue being fixed in 1.3.14, but it seems it is not the case. In 1.3.14 the `finally` property is still accessed with the dot notation.

Comment: You are correct, it is exacly this issue but there is no solution given. Upgrading angular to 1.3.14 gives the same error but in different line, upgrading to 1.4 gives an error on unexpected token return

Comment: There is a *dirty* solution : you could patch yourself angular script by replacing `.finally` with `['finally']`. Searched in angular 1.3.10 and 1.3.14 it seems there is only one occurence. In angular 1.4.0-beta.5 there are two occurences of `.return` line 12584 and 12684.

Comment: If you are using a build tool like grunt or gulp, a better option would be to use a plugin based on [es3-safe-recast](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es3-safe-recast/) that would replace for you all es3 reserved words to their safe alternative with the bracket notation.